# Apache FOP Suppress Warnings

Tags: java, apache, logging, warnings, apache-fop

Recently i configured a Java Web Application with log4j where in backoffice we can lower and upper the level log and work so fine!

This web application is deployed in Tomcat7 and have 3 components (3 wars files):

- Principal war
- FopServer war (with servlet)
- Similar FOP war (without servlet)

Everything works fine except for the part where this system does not have a clean log file, all thanks to FOP which logs unnecessary warnings.

I've looked all over the internet and I can not tell the FOP library that I do not want the warning logs to be written to my catalina.out

What I did so far was:

1. I tried using the system I found to set the common-logging.properties to point to my log4j and set a log4j.properties.
2. I tried pre-defining classes in SimpleLog so that it only log me Error or Fatal

Everything I did was in vain and I do not know what else to do. You know something else I can do.

I remember that I use a FOP jar.

```
 Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:17 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.fo.FONode attributeWarning
WARNING: Warning(0/0): fo:table, table-layout="auto" is currently not supported by FOP
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.LineLayoutManager$LineBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Line 1 of a paragraph overflows the available area. (fo:block, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableLayoutManager getNextKnuthElements
INFO: table-layout="fixed" and width="auto", but auto-layout not supported => assuming width="100%"
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm updateData2
WARNING: Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, location: 0/0)
Jun 30, 2017 11:19:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```